# Make first link active Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code, and I want to make active the first link (tab) so when somebody is visiting the website can see it active. Also when the next tab/link is clicked, the first one (active tab/link) has to convert itself into a normal tab/link (unactive), and so do on!

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function forumhome_tabs_switch(switch_id){
        document.getElementById('forumhome_tabs_switch_content').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById(switch_id).innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript: forumhome_tabs_switch('forumhome_tabs_$forum[forumid]'); return false;">
    <a href="#" tabindex="2" onclick="javascript: forumhome_tabs_switch('forumhome_tabs_$forum[forumid]'); return false;">$forum[title]</a>  
</td>
```

It's not something like:

```
<li><a href="#">1</li> 
<li><a href="#">2</li> 
<li><a href="#">3</li>
...
```

Also cannot be done like that. Thats why I need help. The above code converts 3 links into 3 tabs, so each tab opens a section of the page. I just want to show first tab as active till the second tab is clicked.

P.D. Also I would like to pass the "onclick" from the "a" (links) to javascript code. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand:  `pass the "onclick" from the "a" (links) to javascript code` ?

Comment: When you have an event handler, `this` within the handler function references the element the event was attached to, so that's one way to reference or access the related `a`. If you use `addEventListener()` on the `li`, you could delegate to the `e.target` if the `A` was clicked, e.g., like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwgyK/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean? I can continue it if you wish. http://jsfiddle.net/ftM2b/1/
Essentially there are three "tabs" that change state when another is clicked. You could easily make this into more of a tabs system with pages.

HTML

```
<a class="tab" id="Tab1">Tab1</a>
<a class="tab" id="Tab2">Tab2</a>
<a class="tab" id="Tab3">Tab3</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
$(".tab").click(function() {
$(".tab").css("background-color","blue");
$(this).css("background-color","red");
});
});
```

CSS

```
.tab{
width: 40px;
height: 20px;
background-color: blue;
}
#Tab1{
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The script isnt using that system from above. I mean, the structure of
<a class="tab" id="tab1">Tab1</a>
...
Isnt used. Its only a links "class" "id" call it whatever you want, that changes all the categories link into tabs.

I have only this code:
<td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript: forumhome_tabs_switch('forumhome_tabs_$forum[forumid]'); return false;">
    <a href="#" tabindex="2" onclick="javascript: forumhome_tabs_switch('forumhome_tabs_$forum[forumid]'); return false;">$forum[title]</a>  
</td>

Comment: The see what I mean I would open up my site and show you what I'm working on. 
1. Go to www.1st-hacks.com
2. Scroll page down and select iOS.H style (Default Style is shown by default)
3. On that style you can see 4 categories (1st-hacks, Games Section, Developer Setion and Programmer Section). If you look to those tabs with firebug, you will see 4 TD'S. But In my admin panel I only habe the link I posted above. How can I edit it or what can I do to make the first tab :active till the other ones are clicked?